# R Neuralnet with startweights

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

Just wanted to know if you could help me to impose that the starting weights of a Neural Network Regression, setting them to zero.

I've been trying this code, but it keeps taking random starting weights:

```
nn<-neuralnet(f,data=historico,hidden=c(1),linear.output = T,rep=1,likelihood=F,startweights = c(1:ncol(historico))*0, algorithm='rprop+')
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Your startweights `startweights = c(1:ncol(historico))*0` will just be a vector of zeros!!

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but are you aware that we *never* set the initial weights to zero??

Comment: @G5W I know, but it doesn't work for some reason I don't know

Comment: @desertnaut I know, but just for testing I tried to set them to zero, though it keeps doing a random selection